# How to change the behavior of the keyboard navigation on a Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel (ExtJs)?

Tags: extjs, keyboard-events, gridpanel

I have a Ext.EditorGridPanel (with Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel) class with four columns and many rows. The user is allowed to edit the cells, but after edit it and press ENTER or TAB, I want that the cell editor opens automatically on the next row (not the next column, as the default is), at the same column index.

I tried to use the method startEditing(row,column) on afteredit event, but without success.

Any suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `keys` config option of the `editorgrid`. It accepts an `Object` of `KeyMap`. Check the docs [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.Panel-cfg-keys). If that doesn't work, catch `keypress` event and check if the key matches `Ext.EventObject.ENTER` then do your thing!